# Distributional derivative of a characteristic function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I need some help with this exercise about distributional derivatives:

If we have $N=2$,  and a function $g=\chi_{C}$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function, and $C$ is the unitary cube $C=\lbrace{(x,y): \max\lbrace{|x|,|y|\rbrace}\leq 1\rbrace}$,

Compute the distributional derivatives $D^{(1,1)}g$ and $D^{(1,0)}g$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

---

I arrived at the following results, but i'm not  sure if they are ok :

$\bullet$For $D^{(1,0)}g$:  $<T_g^{(1,0)},\varphi>=-<T_g,\varphi^{(1,0)}>=<\chi_I,\varphi>$

where $I$ is the set $\lbrace{(\pm 1,y): y\in[-1,1]\rbrace}$.

$\bullet$ For $D^{(1,1)}g$: $<T_g^{(1,1)},\varphi>=+<T_g,\varphi^{(1,1)}>=<\chi_I\cdot\chi_S,\varphi>$

where $S=\lbrace{((x,\pm1):x\in[[-1,1]\rbrace}$

Comment: This can't be correct, as $I$ has measure $0$ in $R^2$, so $\int\chi_i\varphi = 0$.

Comment: I will explain what I did, for example for $D^{(1,0)}g$  . Please, tell me where I am wrong:

1.

$<T_g^{(1,0)},\varphi>=-<T_g,\varphi^{(1,0)}>=-\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_C\varphi^{(1,0)}(x,y)\;dxdy=-\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi^{(1,0)}(x,y)\;dxdy=-\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\partial \varphi(x,y)}{\partial x}\;dxdy=-\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(1,y)-\varphi(-1,y)\;dxdy$

Comment: The last integral is just with respect to y ...

Comment: Yes, was a typing error. Looking at those calculations, could we say the following?

$<T_g^{(1,0)},\varphi>=-\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(1,y)-\varphi(-1,y)\;dy=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(-1,y)-\varphi(1,y)\;dy=$

$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}(\delta_{(-1,y)}-\delta_{(1,y)})\chi_{\lbrace (x,y):-1\leq y\leq 1{\rbrace}}\varphi(x,y)\;dxdy=<(\delta_{(-1,y)}-\delta_{(1,y)})\chi_{\lbrace (x,y):-1\leq y\leq 1{\rbrace}},\varphi>$

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a closed expression for this, yours is not defined. But there is a closed expression for D^{(1,1)}T_g$ ... and I guess this is the purpose of your exercise.

Comment: Yes, for $D^{(1,1)}g$, as you have to derivate twice, you eliminate both integrals, and finally I get $<\delta_{(1,1)}-\delta_{(1,-1)}-\delta_{(-1,1)}+\delta_{(-1,-1)},\varphi>$, it's ok?

Comment: yes, looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness and to correct the question, here are the answers:

$$
(D^{(1,0)}T_g)(\varphi) = -\int_{-1}^1 \varphi(-1,y)-\varphi(-1,y) dy \,\text{ and}
$$
$$
D^{(1,1)}T_g = \delta_{(1,1)} - \delta_{(-1,1)}- \delta_{(1,-1)} +\delta_{(-1,-1)}.
$$